# Python: undefined variables at class

Tags: python, class

I am an python beginner.
I tried to write a class.
This class include one variable and one function.
At that function, i user this variable in the if condition statement.
But when I call this class.function, there is an error.
[image]

So i rewrite the code to this, then it works.
[image]
But i am curious why i need to add class name before the variable at if condition? (this if is still parts of the class)
Thanks!

Comment: Please post the code here. That is a static variable. You need to create a copy of that in the methods

Comment: Well, it's a Python design choice :shrug:

Comment: From the Python docs ([Execution model: Resolution of names](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#resolution-of-names)): _"The scope of names defined in a class block is limited to the class block; it does not extend to the code blocks of methods"_.  As a bit of motivation, eliminating "class scope" helps make name resolution simple and fast. To a first approximation, all names refer either to local variables (which can be enumerated at compile time, and indexed as an array at runtime), or global variables (which need to be looked up in a hash table every time at runtime).

Answer (score 1):

Broadly speaking, there are two kinds of variables in Python: local and non-local. Local variables are defined in the current scope; non-local variables are defined in an enclosing scope. (That makes a global variable a special kind of non-local variable, one that is defined in the global scope.)

`supportScrs` is not defined in the `read` function, so it must be a non-local variable. The question is, which scope defines it? The answer is: no scope defines it. A `class` statement does not create a new scope. The only construct in Python that can create a new scope is a function call. `supportScrs` is defined in the *namespace* created by the `class` statement, resulting in it being added to the class itself as an attribute.

As a class attribute, it must be referenced via the class (or an instance of the class):

```
def read(src):
    if src in IO.supportScrs:
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

generally supportScrs is an attribute inside a class IO.
Generally to call or access those variables,we need to call it by it's class name.

```
class_name.attribute
```

so to access supportScrs variable form IO class, you need to call like this below

```
IO.supportScrs
```

Comment: `supportScrs` isn't a local variable, at least not by Python's definition. Bad terminology adds unnecessary confusion here.

Comment: It is a class or static variable

Comment: Hi Kris, thanks for answer. So if the different attributes in the same class want to call each other,  we need to add class name precede the called attributes?